# Is it possible to conditionally enable a non-const/const data member of a template class based on the constness of the template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to conditionally enable a non-const/const data member of a template class based on the constness of the template argument? Or maybe have some conditional typedef? I thought about using std::enable_if with std::is_const, but there is no std::is_not_const that I could use.

```
class A;

template <typename T>
class Test
{
    A& m_a; // If T != const.
    const A& m_a; // If T == const.
};
```

Note that always T != A.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
    typename
    std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, const A&, A&>::type
    m_a;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps this question can also be answered here since it is related. When having some T, would it be wrong to get the 'pure type' with std::remove_const even in cases when T is actually non-const already?

Comment: That's fine. `remove_const` will give back original type if it's not const qualified. But note that `remove_const<const T&>` gives `const T&` as it removes top-level qualifier only.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this. The [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) header has tools for this purpose.

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_const<T>::value,
        typename std::add_const<A>::type,
        typename std::remove_const<A>::type
    >::type m_a;
};
```

- [`std::is_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const)
- [`std::add_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv) / [`std::remove_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv)
- [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

You could even make a helper for this purpose:

```
//T is type to modify
//S is source type to mimic
struct mimic_const<T, S>
{
public:
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_const<S>::value,
        typename std::add_const<T>::type,
        typename std::remove_const<T>::type
    >::type type;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
    typename mimic_const<A, T>::type m_a;
};
```

Comment: `add_const` is a bit of an overkill here.

Comment: Well, `const A` is enough. And you need `typename` there, too.